# Как убрать повторяющиеся слэши в php?

Tags: php

В общем в строке может быть сразу несколько подряд идущих слэшей, может быть `///` и `////` и `//` и т.п. Как это заменить на только один единственный слэш `/`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно регуляркой, как-то так:

```
$text = <<<HTML
В общем в строке может быть сразу несколько подряд идущих слэшей, может быть /// и //// и // и т.п. Как это заменить на только один единственный слэш /?
HTML;
$text = preg_replace('|([/]+)|s', '/', $text);
echo $text;
```